# how to move apex class from developer edition to enterprice edition

Tags: salesforce

i have apex class in developer edition and i want to move this class into enterprice edition using apex expolrer IDE but i am getting error like this "test coverage of selected apex trigger is 0 at least 1 % test coverage is required".The apex class is given below.so kindly let me know as soon as possible.

public class SendEmailToFeedback
{ 
    public SendEmailToFeedback() 
    {

```
}
public SendEmailToFeedback(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{

}
public String items { get; set; }
Opportunity opportunity;
//public String subject{ get; set; }
//public String body { get; set; }
public String lid { get; set; }
public String response {get; set;}
List<Opportunity> Opp;
public PageReference cancel() 
{
    return null;
}   
public List<Opportunity> getOpp()
{
   if(Opp== null)
     {
       lid = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');
       Opp= [Select o.Name,o.Email__c from Opportunity o where o.id =:lid];
     }
    return Opp;
}
public PageReference send() 
{
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String addresses;
    if (Opp[0].Email__c != null)
    {
        addresses = Opp[0].Email__c;

            if (Opp[0].Email__c != null)
            {
                addresses += ':' + Opp[0].Email__C;
                String[] toAddresses = addresses.split(':', 0);
                email.setSenderDisplayName('THYLAKSOFT LLC');
               // email.setSubject(subject);
                email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                email.setPlainTextBody('Click The Followoing Link http://tefllife.com/studentfeedback.html');
                try
               {
                 Messaging.SendEmailResult [] resultMail= Messaging.sendEmail(new
```

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
                     if(resultMail[0].isSuccess())
                     response = 'ok sent!';
                      else
                      {
                         response = resultMail[0].getErrors().get(0).getMessage();
                      }
                    }
                    catch(System.EmailException ex)
                    {
                      response = ex.getMessage();
                    }
                }

```
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to deploy it without also providing the test classes for it, see the docs on [apex testing](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods)