# Average test coverage across all Apex Classes and Triggers is 0%, at least 75% test coverage is required

Tags: salesforce

here i have apex class and visualfource page in developer edition, while i am uploading package i am getting error like"Average test coverage across all Apex Classes and Triggers is 0%, at least 75% test coverage is required"so kindly let me know the solution if possible define code.

```
Apex class:
public virtual class SendEmailToFeedback
{ 
    public String items { get; set; }
    Opportunity opportunity;
    public String subject{ get; set; }
    public String body { get; set; }
    public String lid { get; set; }
    public String response {get; set;}
    List<Opportunity> Opp;


private static testMethod void myShareTest(){


}  


    public PageReference cancel() 
    {
        return null;

    }   
    public List<Opportunity> getOpp()
    {
       if(Opp== null)
         {
           lid = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('name');
           Opp= [Select o.Name,o.Email__c from Opportunity o where o.id =:lid];
         }
        return Opp;

    }
    public PageReference send() 
    {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String addresses;
        if (Opp[0].Email__c != null)
        {
            addresses = Opp[0].Email__c;

                if (Opp[0].Email__c != null)
                {
                    addresses += ':' + Opp[0].Email__C;
                    String[] toAddresses = addresses.split(':', 0);
                    email.setSenderDisplayName('THYLAKSOFT LLC');
                    email.setSubject(subject);
                    email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                    email.setPlainTextBody(body + 'Click The Followoing Link http://tefllife.com/studentfeedback.html');
                    try
                   {
                     Messaging.SendEmailResult [] resultMail= Messaging.sendEmail(new 

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
                     if(resultMail[0].isSuccess())       
                     response = 'ok sent!';
                      else
                      {
                         response = resultMail[0].getErrors().get(0).getMessage();
                      }
                    }
                    catch(System.EmailException ex)
                    {
                      response = ex.getMessage();
                    }   
                }

        }

        return null;
    }

}


Visualforce page:
<apex:page controller="SendEmailToFeedback" id="thePage">
<apex:page
```

Comment: dupe of the same question you asked yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863208/how-to-move-apex-class-from-developer-edition-to-enterprice-edition

Answer (score 4):

Before you can deploy your code or package it for the Force.com AppExchange, 75% of your Apex code must be covered by unit tests, and all of those tests must complete successfully. This is well documented:

- [Documentation on testing Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_testing.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_testing.htm|SkinName=webhelp)
- [Wiki article on Apex Test Methods](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods)
- [Presentation: Apex Test Coverage Best Practices](http://www.salesforce.com/community/crm-best-practices/dreamforce08-developer-sessions/2008-tdf-mastering-apex-best-practices.jsp)

You need to write test methods that cover at least 75% of your code and they need to run successfully. It's as simple as that, and I don't think anyone is going to write your code for you.