# Code coverage Issue while deploying changeset to production

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am trying to deploy change set which contains Custom fields, Apex classes and test classes from sandbox to production. While executing all test class in Sandbox, Overall Code coverage is 86%. But while deploying to production through change set, getting error message " Details: Average test coverage across all Apex Classes and Triggers is 27%, at least 75% test coverage is required." Please advice.

Comment: What was the code coverage of the code you introduced?

Comment: Each apex class is having above 80% in sandbox.

Comment: What is your Production Code Coverage..?

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/4865396/4944034?